# Finding the mishnah in tractate Pesachim that talks about beers

Tags: sources-mekorot, chametz-leaven, mishna, liquor-beer, maseches-pesachim

Can someone please tell me which mishnah in tractate Pesachim talks about the subject of the different beers regarding the laws of chametz?

Comment: You could make this question more answerable and valuable by [edit]ing in information about where you've heard of such a mishna and why you want to find it.

Comment: I read it in the past and I would like to re-learn it

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 2):

The Mishnah is Pesachim 3:1, or in the Bavli, page 42a

Comment: And as the commentaries explain, the Talmud discussed beer that was either all date/fig (kosher for Passover!), or mostly date/fig with some grain (don't eat it, debatable if you're allowed to own it). Today's beer is all grain and is completely chametz.